# Upload image to Facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like fans of our Facebook page to be able to publish images to a specific Album. Although, the app was able to upload an image to a users timeline, the app isn't able to publish it to an album in the fanpage (facebook page of the company). What's wrong, or how can I change the code so I can track the bug.

In an earlier attempt, I was able with a similar script and never-expire token to publish the image onto the wall of the fanpage, but then the app posted it, and I want to see the users name.

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/xxx/";
$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=publish_stream";

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

if(isset($_FILES["source"]["name"]))
{
    try {
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
        $response = $facebook->api(
        '/ALBUMID/photos/',
        'post',
        array(
        'message' => $_POST['message'],
        'source' => '@'.$_FILES["source"]["tmp_name"], 
        'access_token' => 'xxx'
        )
        );
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log('Could not post image to Facebook.');
    }
}

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    } else {
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
};


$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

echo "<br>user id = $user";
echo "<br>page id = $page_id";
echo "<br>page admin = $page_admin";
echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
echo "<br>country = $country";
echo "<br>locale = $locale";
if ($like_status) {
?>
<div id="like">
    You like us.
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" " method="POST">
        Please choose a photo:
        <input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>
        Say something about this photo:
        <input name="message"
        type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($response))
        {
            echo "Image Uploaded. <a href='http://facebook.com/{$response['id']}' target='_blank'>Click here to view</a>";
        }
    ?>

</div>
<?php
}
else {
?>
<div id="niet_leuk">
    You don't like us.
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with facebook opengraph.  You can see the details of it here:   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/246002638848837/

It is marked as low priority, so I wouldn't expect a fix anytime soon.

So right now, you can only post images to a non-user page as the page admin or as the page itself.

Comment: seems to be fixed now